# How to solve $20t + \frac{240}{\pi} \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} =2500$ by hand?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve a calc 1 problem about how long it takes to fill a reservoir.  This is the result of my integration.

$$20t + \frac{240}{\pi} \sin\frac{\pi t}{12}=2500$$

I know the answer is $t = 122.6$ (its an odd book problem), I only figured it out because I used my graphing calculator and found the intersection of the function and $y=2500$.

How can I solve for $t$ by hand?

Comment: In general this sort of problem is not possible without special functions. 122.6 doesn't look like an exact solution, so I would guess you're supposed to approximate numerically.

Comment: OK, so I guess my method was the correct one? I have the student solution manual ( which is kind of useless) and they just show what I came up with and 122.6. But not how they arrived there. Maybe there is a better way on the TI-84? Thanks for the showing the proper format in your edits too.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I never learned how to use a TI-84; if you only need 1 digit of accuracy, I suppose there's a lot of useful ways to get there.

Comment: At the very least, you should divide every term by $20$.

Comment: If you correctly found the numerical solution to that equation using a graphing calculator, that is probably the right method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scale down the equation as

$$t + \frac{12}{\pi} \sin \left( \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)=125$$

Note that the RHS is much larger than the sine term. So, the solution is roughly $t=125$, which can be refined by adding the first-order approximation as follows.

Let $f(t) = t -125 + \frac{12}{\pi} \sin \frac{\pi t}{12} $ and the root $t=125 + \Delta t$. Then,

$$0 = f(125) + f’(125)  \Delta t$$

Solve for $ \Delta t$

$$ \Delta t = - \frac{f(125)}{f’(125)} 
= -\frac{12}{\pi} \frac{\sin \frac{5\pi}{12}}{1+\cos \frac{5\pi}{12}  }
= -\frac{12}{\pi} \tan \frac{5\pi}{24}$$

Thus, the approximate analytic solution is

$$t= 125 -\frac{12}{\pi} \tan \frac{5\pi}{24}\approx 122.1$$

Comment: This is the first really practical example of a linear approximation I've seen since I learned them. Thanks!

Comment: @spence - pleased to know it’s helpful

Answer (score 1):

If by hand you mean without a calculator at all, you need to use some numeric approach.  Because the sine is limited to $\pm 1$ that term cannot be $80$ in absolute value, so we can get a first approximation by ignoring it, which gives $t=125$.  You will need some way to evaluate the sine, but presumably you have a set of tables.  Now I would use fixed point iteration, writing $$t=125-\frac {12}\pi \sin\left(\frac {\pi t}{12} \right)$$
Plug in $125$ on the right, calculate the new $t$ and iterate.  It takes a while to converge because the derivative of the right side is close to $-1$.  Newton's method will converge more quickly at the price of being a bit harder to derive.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you look for the zero of function $$f(t)=t + \frac{12}{\pi} \sin \left( \frac{\pi t}{12} \right)-125$$ and notice that $f(120)=-5$.

So use Taylor expansion
$$f(t)=-5+2 (t-120)+O\left((t-120)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, an *approximation* is then $t=122.5$. This is the same as the first iteration of Newton method.

Sooner or later, you will learn that, for approximating functions, Padé approximants are much better than Taylor series. Using the $[1,2]$ Padé approximant (this is the simplest), the solution will then be
$$t=120+\frac{17280}{6912-25 \pi ^2}$$ Now, remembering that $\pi^2 \sim 10$, this reduces to
$$t=120+\frac{8640}{3331}=120+\frac{8640\times 3}{3331\times 3}=120+\frac{25920}{9993}\sim 120+\frac{25920}{10000}=122.592$$ while the exact solution is $122.598$.